# JavaScriptでコールバック関数が正しく呼ばれない

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Chrome extensionで`popuup.js`から`background.js`に`sendMessage()`関数を呼び出して、更に`background.js`にてcontent scriptからDOMの要素を取得して、その値を使ってAjaxを行ったあとに、`popup.js`のコールバック関数を呼びましたが、Ajaxでデータを取ってくるところまではできますが、その後に`popup.js`のコールバック関数を呼び出しても、データが渡りません。なぜでしょうか。下記にpopup.jsと、background.jsを示します。

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    console.log("cliecked");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      command: "get_text"
    },
    function(response){
      ここで表示されるはずだが表示されない
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(result){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(result.shift().id, {
      command: "get_dom"
    },
    function(msg) {
      console.log("result message:", msg);
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://localhost:3000",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          text: msg
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          //コールバック関数呼び出し
          sendResponse(data);
        }
      })
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: success時にのみしかコールバックが呼ばれませんが、
ajaxリクエストがerrorで落ちているのでは？
デバッグしてみてください。

Comment: その前のconsole.logで受信している情報を表示できているので、それはないと思います。

Comment: こちらの質問（http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19411）と基本的に同じ内容かと思いますが、やり方はあっていると思います。popup, backgroundそれぞれのconsole.logの結果も掲載していただけると嬉しいです。